# How can I setup the Cygwin X server as a service?

Tags: cygwin, automation, windows-services, x-server, cygwin-x

I've read the Cygwin/X user's [guide](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/cygwin-x-ug.pdf); I've installed Cygwin, the X-related packages, and am able to run X and apps on X.

However - that's all manual. I need to invoke `startxwin` and need to call `xhost +whatever`.

My question: How can I have the X server run as a service, automatically when Windows starts, with some persisted permission settings?

PS - I'm on Windows 10 and my Cygwin is up-to-date.

Comment: X-Server makes sense only if you are logged on to a Desktop - so why not just put it into a batch file in your autostart?

Comment: @EugenRieck: Maybe I ssh'ed into the Windows bock and want to show, say, `xclock`, on the screen? ... granted, that creates other problems (like the login screen). But the point is that when you run the X server, it doesn't detach from the controlling terminal; you'd also need to daemonize it somehow, and AFAICR on Windows that means making it a service.

Comment: Showing xclock on the login screen doesn't fullfill my definition of "making sense" ;-) Daemonizing is easy even unter windows: `Set sh=CreateObject("WScript.Shell") ; sh.Run "some.bat", 0 ; Set sh=Nothing`. Or just use nircmd.

Comment: @EugenRieck: Can you make that into a full answer? Is that regular Windows batch, or PowerShell?

Comment: It's wscript and I made an answer

Answer (score 0):

After discussion in the comments it turns out, that the problem can be reduced to detaching the X-Server from its shell window. There are a few ways to achieve this:

- "onboard": Create a .vbs file  containing

.

```
Set sh=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "some.bat", 0
Set sh=Nothing
```

And run it with `wscript`

- "onboard, cheating": Use the Task scheduler with an "onboot" or "onlogon" task
- "third party": Use `nircmd` and run `nircmd exec hide /path/to/batch.bat`

Comment: It's not that the problem can be reduced to that, but rather that it satisfies most of what I wanted. But - please also elaborate about the "task scheduler" - I haven't used that before. I also don't understand what you mean by "cheating". I don't know what `nircmd` is and where to get it from.

Comment: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

Comment: By "cheating" I ment that it not actually is initiated by the user in the Desktop Session.